# Can't open .jpg files extracted from an .iso, what to do?

Tags: jpeg, eog

Recently, I extracted some pictures from an `.iso` file, but I can't see them. When I try to open these `.jpg` files with Image Viewer, it shows me this error:

> Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0xda)

(the expression after `0x` is different from file to file)

I tried changing the file extension but no result.
Thanks for help!

Comment: Please 1) Open Applications ▸ Accessories ▸ Terminal. 2) Type `file`, followed by a space. 3) Click and drag the picture into the terminal window. 4) Press Enter.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Judging from the error reported by the image viewer, I would say that the files are probably either corrupt or they're not really JPEG files.

What is the result of:

```
file the_file_name.jpg
```

The answer will likely be the actual type of the file.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes your image viewer has not installed the Eye Of Gnome (EOG) plugins. Go to the Software Centre then select 'plugins for eog' and then click 'install', then it should work.